# Failure to adjust item amount

Tags: php, pdo

Hi am am using the code below to check if the item with the same pid, length and category is already in the shopping basket and if it is, it should adjust the quantity of the item. The issue is that if you add an item with the same pid, length and category, instead of the quantity increasing. It is added to the shopping basket as a new product.

```
NOTE: An item has the same pid but it comes in different sizes and category.

    if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
        $pid = $_POST['pid'];
        $length = $_POST["size"];
        $qty = $_POST['Qty'];
        $Category = $_POST['Category'];

        $wasFound = false;
        $i = 0;
        if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
            $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "length" => $length, "Category" => $Category, "quantity" => $qty));
        } else {
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
                  $i++;
                  while (list($key, $value, $ilength, $pcategory) = each($each_item)) {
                      if ($key == "item_id"  && $ilength == $length && $pcategory == $Category && $value == $pid) {

                          array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "length" => $length, "Category" => $Category, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                          $wasFound = true;
                      } 
                  } 
               } 
               if ($wasFound == false) {
                   array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "length" => $length, "Category" => $Category, "quantity" => $qty));
               }
        }
        header("location: cart.php"); 
        exit();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: add a test condition for your requirement

Comment: @DevZer0 what u mean please?

Comment: Not sure if that array_splice() is supposed to be there or just a stackoverflow misstype

Comment: @KyleK i used it... dont know any other alternative to it. Please the anser u posted before is still doing the same thing array_push still working the same way in this case

Comment: @IMSoP can you take a look at this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give this a try ;)
updated and tested Code

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $array_key=>$each_item) { 
              if ($each_item['item_id'] == $pid  && $each_item['length'] == $length && $each_item['Category'] == $Category) {
                      $_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity']+=$qty;
                      $wasFound = true;
              } 
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "length" => $length, "Category" => $Category, "quantity" => $qty));
    } else {
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $key=>$each_item) { 

            if(($each_item['item_id']==$pid && ($each_item['length']==$length)&&($each_item['Category']==$Category)){
                  $_SESSION["cart_array"][$key]['quantity']++;
                  $wasFound = true;
                      $wasFound = true;
                }
            }  

           if ($wasFound == false) {
               array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "length" => $length, "Category" => $Category, "quantity" => $qty));
           }
    }
    header("location: cart.php"); 
    exit();
}
```

Comment: It is still adding the same item, length and category instead of increasing the same quantity

Comment: I added the category because u missed that out and it doesnt show it now... if i add the same item with the same length and different category it doesnt show instead it update the previous one