# Quantity Not adjusting

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to adjust the quantity of an item when a user enters the quantity and click on Update but I am having a problem getting it to work. When you end the quantity and click on update, it does nothing. Below is my php code

PHP code

```
<?php start_session(); ?>


<?php 
if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity);
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $array_key=>$each_item) { 
              if ($each_item['item_id'] == $pid  && $each_item['item_to_adjust'] == $item_to_adjust && $each_item['length'] == $length && $each_item['Category'] == $Category) {
                      $_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity']=$quantity;
                      $wasFound = true;
}
}


}
?>
```

FORM

```
echo '<form action="cart.php" method="post">
<input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
<input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="Update" />
<input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
</form>';
?>
```

Comment: @C.kosan I am having issue updating the quantity of the item

Comment: what's that `$length` value?

Comment: I'm confused. You have both `$qty = $_POST['Qty'];` and `$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];` for **Quantity**, which one is it? **Qty** in layman's terms means "Quantity".

Comment: @Sharky it is posted from a different page to the cart page... I have update it

Comment: @ Fred they is nothing to get confuse about. Qty is posted from a product page. and $quantity is POSTed from the FORM page... IN the FORM code shown above.

Comment: @user2510447 Then why show it, and is it relevant to the problem at hand?

Comment: @Fred I took it off now... Thought it might help

Comment: @user2510447 Ok, that avoids any confusion. Now, as Sharky stated below, talked about `session_start()`. You said and I quote "*I have a session start above that also i am not using Ajax a form... look below the code*". I don't it see it anywhere in your "posted code". If it's in there, then edit your question and place it where you say it's supposed to be. When posting a question, it is **vital** that you post anything and everything related to the problem you are having. Theoretically, Sharky is right; `session_start();` **must** be inside (and usually on top) of every page affected.

Comment: @user2510447 One thing I found is this in `$_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity']=$Quanity;` isn't that supposed to be `=$Quantity;`, or is that a **typo**? It reads as `=$Quanity;`. That could be your problem, **IF** it's not a typo on your part.

Comment: @Fred just a note also OP must check if he needs `=$Quantity` or `+=Quantity` in that point

Comment: @user2510447 Then again, I think that should be `=$quantity`, because you have `$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];` (quantity) all in lowercase letters, as opposed to the other one I commented above, starts with an Uppercase letter, as in 'mixed case'.

Comment: @Sharky I'm not sure about that Sharky, you could be right, however he's going to have to **keep his naming convention consistent**, either keep all variables in lowercase letters, or mixed case. Right now, it's **both**, which doesn't "add up". **Pardon the pun**, plus he needs to check his **$Quanity**.

Comment: @user2510447 **FYI** - QUANTITY (uppercase) - quantity (lowercase) - Quantity (mixed case).

Comment: @Fred I have correct my typo, change the Q to q and the += but still nothing.

Comment: @user2510447 Your `['quantity']=$Quantity;` should read as `['quantity']=$quantity;` with lowercase `q`, whether the problem is there or not. You must "follow suit" with your `$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];`. `quantity` is all in lowercase. Your edit still shows `Quantity`.

Comment: @user2510447 Scratch my last comment. I noticed it just now, SO didn't refresh the page as it usually does.

Comment: @user2510447 I noticed you placed `<?php session_start(); ?>`. Try getting rid of those 2 lines and placing it (`only session_start();`) either underneath `if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {` or above `if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {`. It might be breaking it, due to the closing `?>` tag.

Comment: @user2510447 Also, try adding `if (isset($_POST['quantity'])) {` below `if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {`

Comment: @Fred I have other codes below the

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248734/failure-to-adjust-item-amount/17248926?noredirect=1#comment24997878_17248926

Comment: @user2510447 I also noticed another thing in `<input name="adjustBtn'` - Your `adjustBtn` variable is not mentioned anywhere in your (posted) code. It's just **sitting there** and not being called by anything. I think that could be causing the problem.

Comment: @user2510447 Ok, I'm not 100% sure about this, but try replacing `$_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity']=$quantity;` with `$_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity']=$adjustBtn;` - changing `$quantity` to `$adjustBtn`.

Comment: @user2510447 Sorry, I don't have time to view a video. That's the best help I can give you at this point. But I can tell you this, it has to do with your `<input name="adjustBtn'` - That is what's **controlling** your quantity updating. Your `adjustBtn` variable is not doing anything else and not being **called** by anything, in any way, shape or form.

Comment: @Fredi will echo out and see if the value i have enter have been sent

Comment: @Fred I have echo out and i can see that the value i enter has been sent so it have nothing to do with the <input name="adjustBtn'

Its something to do with my foreach statement

Comment: @user2510447 then you'll have to start troubleshooting by doing `var dumps`.

Answer (score 0):

i don't see any

`session_start();`

In your PHP code, if you want to work with the session of the user, you must include `session_start();` in the beginning of your php file.

**That includes ajax files.**

If you make an ajax call from a php page that has session_start, that DOES NOT MEAN that the ajax script will be "in session". You MUST include `session_start();` in the ajax script.

Comment: session_start should be boxed by an if statement. Or it starts a new session on each page load. `<?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); ?>`

Comment: I have a session start above that also i am not using Ajax a form... look below the code

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ `session_start()` must be used in every page load. you can't use `session_start()` in `index.php` and then navigate to `controlpanel.php` and expect to be in-session. you are completely wrong or i have not understand what you saying

Comment: you got me wrong. I say, session must be started if it has not been started already.

Comment: I have session_start in every page because this is a cart... THE ISSUES ISNOT with the session_start

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ yes, if you have included files etc... in this case you must have an if statement, otherwise (from manual): `As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() after the session was previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply be ignored.`

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to loop through `$_SESSION["cart_array"]` if you already know the id.
this will give you are rough idea of what to do. it is easy to understand and change to your needs!

```
<?php session_start();

$itemid=(int)$_POST['itemid'];
$quantity=(int)$_POST['quantity'];
$size=(int)$_POST['size'];

$i = md5("$itemid # $size"); // id with size for cart array id

if (isset($_SESSION["cart_array"][$i])) {
$_SESSION["cart_array"][$i]['quantity']+=$quantity;
}
else
{
$_SESSION["cart_array"][$i] = array('id'=>$itemid,'size'=>$size,'quantity'=>$quantity); 
}

print_r($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
?>

<p>item 1 - s= <?php echo($_SESSION["cart_array"][md5("1 # 1")]['quantity']); // debug purposes ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="itemid" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input name="quantity" type="text" value="" size="1" maxlength="2" />
<select name="size">
  <option value="1">s</option>
  <option value="2">m</option>
  <option value="3">l</option>
</select>
<input name="adjustBtn" type="submit" value="Add" />
</form></p>

<p>item 2
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="itemid" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input name="quantity" type="text" value="" size="1" maxlength="2" />
<select name="size">
  <option value="1">s</option>
  <option value="2">m</option>
  <option value="3">l</option>
</select>
<input name="adjustBtn" type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
</p>
```

you can learn alot from here [programmers bible](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: an item have 1 item but it comes in different category and size . The way u have suggested means if i have an item with the same id but different size and category in the cart. It will mess everything up

Comment: the id would be `md5(id.size)`

Comment: thats confusing me... why did u add the `select` and the code is to Update the quantity not `+` it

Comment: the issue with that code for me is that it duplicate table and changes the quantity for the second copy.. which it should not duplicate the table