# Show default img if original not available

Tags: php

I am trying to show a default image (coming_soon.png)if the image originally image is not in the image file. 
I have try different methods found on the internet but none of them works. Can someone help please. Thanks

```
<img src="<?php fetchdir($php); ?>thumbnail.php?file=<?php echo $row['ImageFile']; ?>&amp;width=468&amp;height=309&amp;dir=product" />
```

Comment: Can't you take care of that inside `thumbnail.php`?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have tried but nothing. I have added the thumbnail.php code to it

Comment: What have you tried and how did it not work? Catching the result of the `file_get_contents()` and outputting some other image if it failed should be sufficient.

Comment: @Pekka웃 onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='default.jpg'"

Comment: As said, you can do this inside `thumbnail.php` as described above. No need to use Javascript.

Comment: @Pekka웃 give me any example please

Comment: Instead of `or die("Cannot create new image");` do something like `or { echo file_get_contents("default.jpg"); die(); }`

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks for the idea but that just stopped all the other images showing

Comment: Why not just copy the default image into the location and then overwrite it when the actual image is available? Seems easier thing to do.

Comment: @Ed Heal that's what I am trying to do. So if the orginal image is not in the image file then it should put a default image instead and then it will overwrite when the actual image is added

Comment: What is the image file? Why not put the default image in its place until it will become available!

Comment: @Ed Heal that's an easy way of doing it but isn't they a way just say if image is not found show default image

Comment: @user2510447 - Why do the complicated thing when the easy solution works?

Comment: @EdHeal i might as well do that

Comment: Can someone take a look at this posted and see if they can help me out. I still haven't found anything wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249770/quantity-not-adjusting

Answer (score 0):

I have a CMS that has a similar set-up: a class that handles the creation of thumbnails, and a script that instantiates this class, re-sizes uploads and saves them to a thumbnail directory. This script is called like this:

`thumb.php/upload.jpg/400/300/contain`

In your instance, you could add another parameter that’s the filename of your default image. So in my case, I could have something like:

```
function get_thumbnail($filename, $width, $height, $type, $default) {
    if (file_exists($uploads_dir . $filename) {
        return sprintf('thumb.php/%s/%d/%d/%s', $filename, $width, $height, $type);
    }
    else {
        return $default;
    }
}
```

Hopefully that points you in the right direction for your scenario.

Comment: i see what you trying to do they very clever, this actually just gave me an idea for something else :D thanks

Comment: No problem. I know it wasn’t a direct answer to your own code, but posted it in the hope it pointed you on the right path. Benefit of passing default filename as a parameter is it can be configured on a per-case basis then, rather than being site-wide.

Answer (score -2):

just put default image in database if no image.

or

where `$sImagePath`

```
if (!file_exists($sImagePath)) {
{
   // load default link
$sImagePath = 'default image file';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php