# JQuery Onclick display selected info

Tags: php, jquery, sql, pdo

I want to display the selected  `price`, `category` and `size` on the dropdown `slideingDiv`. But what I have done below is not working. I have try to echo out to see if the data have been sent thought but I got nothing. Is anything wrong with my code?

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Button

```
<button a href="product.php?ProdID=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="show_hide" id="button" name="button">Add to cart</a></button>
```

PHP

```
<?php
                    dbconnect();
                    if(isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['length']) && isset($_POST['Qty']) &&     `isset($_POST['Category'])){`  
            $pid = $_POST['pid'];
            $length = $_POST["length"];
            $qty = $_POST['Qty'];
            $Category = $_POST['Category'];

            echo $pid;     // I have add this echo to see data have been passed though but i get nothing in return
            echo $length; 

                $stmt4 = $conn->prepare("
                SELECT Product.Name as ProductName, Category.Name, size, Price
                FROM item_Product, Product, Category
                WHERE Product.ProdID =:pid
                AND size= :length  AND Category.Name = :Category Limit  1");
                $stmt4->bindParam('pid',$pid);
                $stmt4->bindParam('length',$length); 
                $stmt4->bindParam('Category',$Category); 
                $stmt4->execute();
                foreach ($stmt4->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row4 ) {
                $product_name = $row4["ProductName"];
                $price = $row4["Price"];
                $length = $row4["size"];    
                $Category = $row4["Name"];

                ?>

                Item was added shopping bag </br>
                Name:<?php echo $row4['ProductName']; ?> </br>
                Length:<?php echo $row4['size']; ?> </br>
                Category:<?php echo $row4['Name']; ?> </br>
                Price:<?php echo $row4['Price']; ?> </br>

                <?php } } 
                ?>
                <a href="cart.php">View Cart</a>
                </div>
```

TABLE

```
<td width="160">Price:</td>
                echo '<td name="pricetag" id="pricetag">'.$row2['Price'].'</td>';

</tr>
    <tr>    
<td>Category</td>   
    <td>
<select id="Category" name="Category">
        echo '<option value="'.$row['Name'].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>';

</select>
</td>
</tr>

     <tr>
    <td width="160">Length:</td>
                        <td>
    <select name="length" id="length">

<option SELECTED value="'.$row3['size'].'">'.$row3['size'].</option>

</select>
</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quantity</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Qty" id="Qty" value="1" style="width: 20px; text-align: right" /></td>

                    </tr>       
                </table>    
                <div class="cleaner h20"></div>
                <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                <div class="button">
                <button class="show_hide" id="button" name="button">Add to cart</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: whats the problem with this?

Comment: sorry guys, I have update the question

Comment: Add a space after the `<?php ` tag : `<?php } `

Comment: Try to put space between `<?php` and closing curly brace.

Comment: I dont have that error anymore but the code is not working. I have echo out the `$pid`, `$length`, etc but no data have been sent though

Comment: @Brewal i have fix that. Thanks but why isn't the data posting

Comment: @emely See if you have a data in the database or you have a data that meets your `WHERE` condition

Comment: @NesmarPatubo Yes i have the issue is that the date is send i have check by echoing `echo $pid;`& `echo $length;` and nothingis sent

Comment: @NesmarPatubo I have edit it to show where i have add the `echo`

Comment: @Emily can you post your `HTML` code too?

Comment: @Þaw thats alot of codes. `table`

Comment: @Emily dont post all of them, just the one used in your problem

Comment: @Þaw DONE I have cut down the `PHP` and `query` for the `Category`, `Price` and `Length`

Comment: @Emily so when you click the button you want to display it?

Comment: yes basically the button does two things. 1 it sends the item to cart(THIS IS WORKing) and 2 it called the `script` above which should show the item added to the cart. So it should depends the length, category and the Name of the product. The query in the `PHP` is what i am using for the cart page. So the same query should work for what I am trying to do

Comment: I cannot add ajax call because the button is already making an ajax call to add an item to cart without leaving the product page

Comment: @Emily ok i Get it , ill make a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: **[SEE MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2nY89/69/)**

**HTML**

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>
        <select id='priceTag'>
            <option value='p1'>price 1</option>
            <option value='p2'>price 2</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>
        <select id='Category'>
            <option value='c1'>cat 1</option>
            <option value='c2'>cat 2</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Size</td>
        <td>
        <select id='Size'>
            <option value='s1'>size 1</option>
            <option value='s2'>size 2</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id='button'>Submit</button>
<div id='selected'>
    <table cellpadding="5" border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>Price:</td>
            <td id='sprice'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category:</td>
            <td id='scat'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Size:</td>
            <td id='ssize'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#selected').hide();
    $('#button').click(function()
    {
        var price = $('#priceTag').val();
        var cat = $('#Category').val();
        var size = $('#Size').val();

        $('#sprice').text(price);
        $('#scat').text(cat);
        $('#ssize').text(size);

        $('#selected').slideDown();
    });
});
```

Comment: the price is not a select option. Its a <tr>
    `<td width="160">Price:</td>
    <td name="pricetag" id="pricetag"></td></tr>`
`NOTE:` The price changes depending on what size you choose

Comment: OK, so remove the select option, and its ok

Comment: `var price = $('#priceTag').val();` how do you call a none `value` in Jquery because i need to call the pricetag also who can I need to add the qty with the price. Please help

Comment: you need to put something like a `<p>` inside the `<td>` just use something like `<p id='priceTag'></p>` and call it same as `$('#priceTag').text()` in JQuery

Comment: `.Text()` never knew that. Thanks but how will i multiple the price with   the quantity and show it?

Comment: @Emily thats very simple, do your computation in javascript before showing it.

Comment: please check 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249770/quantity-not-adjusting I am having issue with that code too

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you do not have a space in your `<?php} ?>`

Do something like `<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Error:

```
<?php} ?>
```

try this,

```
<?php } ?> // add space between php and }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php}
should be
 <?php }
```

Also

`<button a href="product.php?ProdID=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="show_hide" id="button" name="button">Add to cart</a></button>` is in correct

should be

```
<button><a href="product.php?ProdID=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="show_hide" id="button" name="button">Add to cart</a></button>
```

Comment: the data still not passed though

Comment: also i dont want to load the page, I want the user to see the detail they have added