# Ajax not showing £ sign

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to show the British pound sign but it is not working. I have try using the html codes for pound signs still nothing.

**I have try this**

```
var price = '£' + parseInt($('#pricetag').text(),10) * qty;
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#selected').hide();
    $('#button').click(function()
    {
        var qty = $('#Qty').val();
        var price = '£' + parseInt($('#pricetag').text(),10) * qty;


        $('#sprice').text(price);


        $('#selected').slideDown();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BsExr/) fyi.. it seems to working fine here

Comment: You might want to specify you encoding in your document with a `meta` tag (HTML5 --> `<meta charset="UTF-8">`) in between your `head` tags. Otherwise you give the freedom of choice to the browser for the encoding. Who knows, your browser might detect your page and encode it in `ISO8859-1` or something like that.

Comment: Works fine for me as well.

Comment: Your exact code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/wdAkz/2/

Comment: @Ghillied i did that but it didnt work :D but it didnt work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249770/quantity-not-adjusting/17284492?noredirect=1#comment25098264_17284492

Can someone see what is wrong with the foreach statement pleasE?

Comment: @Emily If the page has some PHP in it, the server might **override** the charset. Try adding this on top of your php code: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote [Douglass Crockford via JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html):

> There are characters that are handled inconsistently in browsers, and so must be escaped when placed in strings.
>   \u0000-\u001f \u007f-\u009f \u00ad \u0600-\u0604 \u070f \u17b4 \u17b5 \u200c-\u200f \u2028-\u202f \u2060-\u206f \ufeff \ufff0-\uffff

I highly suggest you use the unicode escape for £ `\u00A3` that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var price = '&#163;' + parseInt($('#pricetag').text(),10) * qty;
$('#sprice').html(price);
```